# What are the best natural foods to help reduce gynechomastia?

Tags: treatment-options, effectiveness, breast, soy, gynecomastia-man-boobs

The internet has contradictory information on this topic. Some say soy is good, some say it is not.

What are the recommended foods to help reduce gynechomastia in men (men boobs)?

Comment: The best treatment is to visit an endocrinologist and find out why you have a hormonal imbalance and get that fixed. If it's due to steroid abuse, stopping the steroids would be a good first step. However, any breast tissue already present is permanent and cannot be reduced except by surgery.

Answer (score 1):

Foods that may reduce Gynocamastia:

- [Livestrong:](http://www.livestrong.com/article/526346-foods-for-gynecomastia/)

> there's no association between any food and breast enlargement in men,
>   and no special food you need to eat or avoid when you have the
>   condition.

That said you can try food that are anti-inflammatory dor tenderness, low calorie to decrease total body fat, and avoiding foods that may encourage it.

Low calorie:

> fruits, vegetables, whole grains, nonfat dairy foods and lean sources
>   of protein such as poultry, lean red meat, seafood and beans.

[Anti-inflammatory:](http://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/foods-that-fight-inflammation)

> tomatoes. olive oil. green leafy vegetables, such as spinach, kale,
>   and collards. nuts like almonds and walnuts. fatty fish like salmon,
>   mackerel, tuna, and sardines. fruits such as strawberries,
>   blueberries, cherries, and oranges.

[ncbi.nlh.nim.gov](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18558591)

Showed some evidence to breast growth and tenderness after soy usage.

[Medscape.com](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/576784)

Tea tree oil and lavender oil have been linked to Gynecomastia.

> including drugs that decrease testosterone synthesis such as
>   ketoconazole, metronidazole, or cytotoxic agents and drugs that
>   decrease testosterone action such as marijuana, cimetidine, flutamide,
>   and spironolactone. Furthermore, some drugs such as isoniazid,
>   penicillamine, calcium channel blockers, and central nervous system
>   agents (including diazepam, tricyclic antidepressants, reserpine,
>   phenytoin, and amphetamines)[4](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/576784) can cause gynecomastia via an unknown
>   mechanism of action

***You need to consult your doctor if you are experiencing any symptoms for other possible interventions or disturbances a change in diet could cause.***